# Cannot modify association 'SomeModels' because it goes through more than one other association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am getting an error when trying to create/edit an instance that has a few "has_many ... through" elements. I have been looking for a workaround, I have tried to add ", :autosave => false" on a few and on all the relations but nothing seems to work.

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly at /customer/new

Cannot modify association 'Customer#shops' because it goes through more than one other
association.
```

This is my `Customer` model which is the one I want to create/edit:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :customer_shop_groups
  has_many :shop_groups, -> { order(:name) }, through: :customer_shop_groups
  has_many :shops, -> { order(:name) }, through: :shop_groups
  has_one  :api_consumer
end
```

And these are the models which also have 'has_many...through' dependencies :

This is my `CustomerShopGroup` model:

```
class CustomerShopGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :shop_group
  has_many :shops, through: :shop_group
end
```

This is my `ShopGroup` model:

```
class ShopGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
  has_many :customer_shop_groups
  has_many :customers, through: :customer_shop_groups
  has_many :shop_group_maps, -> { order 'level' }, class_name: 'Map'
  has_many :heatmaps, through: :shop_group_maps
  scope :with_friendly_id, lambda { |friendly_id| where(friendly_id: friendly_id) }
end
```

And this is my `ApiConsumer` model:

```
class ApiConsumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :shops, through: :customer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to save Shops in the Customer form, but it will not work. One way you could do it is replacing `has_many :shops, -> { order(:name) }, through: :shop_groups` creating a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not quite what I'm trying to do. A Shop may belong to one or more Customer, but it may also belong to one or more ShopGroup. ShopGroup is also used to name a group of shops, simulation a certain hierarchy.